# Scratch disk visibility on Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've started an instance which had a -d at the back (this should be a scratch disk).

But on boot the disk space stated is not seen.

It should be:

```
8 vCPUs, 52 GB RAM, 2 scratch disks (1770 GB, 1770 GB)
```

But `df -h` outputs:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           10G  644M  8.9G   7% /
/dev/root        10G  644M  8.9G   7% /
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           377M  116K  377M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           753M     0  753M   0% /run/shm
```

so how does one get to run an instance with boot that's a persistent disk and have scratch disks available?

The thing is that I need high CPU and lots of scratch space.

Answer (score 8):

`df` does not show scratch disks because they are not formatted and mounted. Issue the following command:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
```

In the output there will be something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root ... scsi-0Google_EphemeralDisk_ephemeral-disk-0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root ... scsi-0Google_EphemeralDisk_ephemeral-disk-1 -> ../../sdc
```

Then, you can use `mkfs` and `mount` the appropriate disks.

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#formatscratch) for more info.